# AWS Elastic Beanstalk Installing Zip

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, laravel-5, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am using PHP 7.1 on an Elastic Beanstalk Laravel app. In my app I am using a library that requires the PHP Zip extension enabled. I have tried many ways to install the extension using Yum. I have tried

```
yum install php-zip
yum install php71-php-pecl-zip
```

but nothing seems to work. What how am I meant to install these items into an Elastic Beanstalk app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First try `dnf search` or `yum search` to look up the exact name of the package. After installing, make sure the extension is loaded with `php -m`. You can load the extension by adding this line to your php.ini file:

```
extension=zip
```

Make sure you are adding it to the correct php.ini file since some servers use a separate path for Php under Apache and Php under CLI.